# JPA - Create or use Foreign Key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Okay I have 2 entities -:

- Teacher
- Department

One teacher can belong to one department and one department can have many teachers.

So the requirement is that Teacher entity contains a mappedBy attribute that maps the relation.

Now the problem that I am facing is that if a Department does not exist then it is created and if not a query fetches the department and that is used in the the teacher object.

Now the problem is that if the Department exists I have to use merge() if not I have to use persist() since the department will be newly inserted. Is there anything I can do that allows for dynamic use of merge or persist ?

The code is as follows-:

Department.java

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "DEPARTMENTS")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Department.findById",
            query = "SELECT d FROM "
                    + "Department d "
                    + "WHERE d.deptId = :id")
})
public class Department extends STSEntity{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column (name = "DEPT_ID", length = 10, 
            unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String deptId;

    @OneToMany (targetEntity = Teacher.class, 
            mappedBy = "dept")
    private Collection<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Teacher.java

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "TEACHER_DATA")
@NamedQueries ( {
    @NamedQuery(name = "Teacher.getByDept",
            query = "SELECT t "
                    + "FROM Teacher t "
                    + "WHERE t.dept = :dept")
})
public class Teacher extends STSEntity {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column (name = "TEACHER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String teacherId;

    @ManyToOne (targetEntity = Department.class, 
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn (name = "DEPT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Department dept;
```

Anyway I can use both ? Any help will be appreciated

Basically if the foreign key exists use it or otherwise create it.

Comment: Why don't you just use merge and let JPA figure out if it requires an insert or an update?

Comment: @Chris Merge() only works when there is a department present. Otherwise it tries to persist duplicate values of departments if I try to persist more than one Teacher.

Comment: After you merge first teacher, use the department from the merged teacher and use it on other teachers.

Comment: You should set both sides of the relations, so that all new teacher instances are associated to the same existing department.  If you add the CascadeType.Merge to the department.teachers relationship, you then only need to merge your department to have all new teachers inserted in the database.